# While loop with an if statement

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, loops

```
def subStringMatchExact(word,subword):
    if len(word)<len(subword):
        print 'substring is bigget than the string, please type another substring.'
        return None    
    else:
        for i in xrange(0,len(word)):
            t = ()
            j = 0
            while word[i] == subword[j]:
                j = j+1 
                i = i+1
                if j == len(subword):
                    t = t+(i-j,)
                    return t



print subStringMatchExact('afgbcdefg', 'fg')
```

How can I make the loop start again and it to keep track of the value of `i`?

Comment: Any reason not to use `subword in word` and `word.index(subword)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of `i`"?

Comment: So when the loop continues it keeps on from the point it left off because of the if statement.

Comment: modifying a for-loop-varible while looping over it is bad, very bad. If you have to modify while looping use a while-loop!

Comment: It seems like your code is working fine.. I am not sure why would you want to do that? Also, you should use a list to keep track of indexes and append to it. Tuples are immutable, so why take the pain of creating a new one every time? Oh, and you would be better of nuking this code and using `in` operator like @TimPietzcker told.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which loop you want to run again, but the only way to do that after it ends, is to put it in another loop. You can keep track of i, by storing it in another variable outside the scope of the for loop.
Like this:

```
def subStringMatchExact(word,subword):
    if len(word)<len(subword):
        print 'substring is bigger than the string, please type another substring.'
        return None
    else:
        lasti=0 # <- lasti is outside the scope of the for loop 
                # So it will save the value even after the for loop terminates
        for i in xrange(0,len(word)):
            t = []
            j = 0
            lasti=i # assigning i to lasti 
            while word[i] == subword[j]:
                j = j+1
                i = i+1
                if j == len(subword):
                    t = t+(i-j,)
                    return t
```

If you're trying to get the starting and ending position of the subword than you could do this:

```
def subStringMatchExact(word,subword):
    if len(word)<len(subword):
        print 'substring is bigger than the string, please type another substring.'
        return None
    else:
        start, end = -1, -1
        for i in range(0,len(word)):
            for  j in range(0,len(subword)):
                if word[i] == subword[j]:
                    if start == -1:
                        start = i
                    end = (j+i-1)
        return [start,end]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to improvise the code to continue from where the string match is wrong, `For` loop is not the way to go. this will be helpful:

```
def subStringMatchExact(word,subword):
    if len(word)<len(subword):
        print 'substring is bigget than the string, please type another substring.'
        return None    
    else:
        i = 0
        while i < len(word):
            t = ()
            j = 0
            while word[i] == subword[j]:
                j = j+1 
                i = i+1
                if j == len(subword):
                    t = t+(i,)
                    return t
```

You cannot jump or leap forward in terms of for loop. You need to use while loop for that. Please note that for anything other than educational purpose, do not go this route. This can be done easily using the string index method:

```
def subStringMatchExact(word,subword):
    if len(word) < len(subword):
        print 'substring is bigger than the string, please type another substring.'
    if subword in word:
        word_index = word.index(subword)
        return tuple(range(word_index, word_index+len(subword)))
```